# SQLAlchemy: reflecting tables of existing database not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, postgresql, sqlalchemy, reflect

I am currently engaged in evaluating SQLAlchemy for a new project. When trying to reflect the tables of an existing database (postgres, oracle), I am encountering some issues.

In order to connect to an Oracle database the following code is being used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, inspect, select
import pandas as pd
import keyring

dbtype = 'Oracle'
dbenv = 'LOCAL'
dbname = 'MYDB'
dbsys = '%s%s' % (dbtype, dbenv)
dbusr = 'myusr'
dbpwd = keyring.get_password(dbsys, dbusr)
dbhost = 'mydbhost'
dbport = 1521

dbconstr = 'oracle+cx_oracle://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (dbusr, dbpwd, dbhost, dbport, dbname)
engine = create_engine(dbconstr)
```

After some try-and-error regarding how to assemble the connection string (there is no `tnsnames.ora` present on my system), I managed to successfully establish a connection to the remote Oracle database.

When inspecting the database and trying to retrieve the names of the tables available, I received an empty list.

```
inspector = inspect(engine)
instbls = inspector.get_table_names()
print('instbls: %s' % instbls)

# instbls: []
```

What I actually was expecting is that the system tables or the public tables would have been listed.

Next I tried reflecting the database tables of the `SYS` schema.

```
md01 = MetaData(bind=engine, schema=['SYS', 'SYSTEM'], reflect=True)
# Warning: sqlalchemy_oracle.py:37: SADeprecationWarning: The MetaData.reflect flag is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.   Please use the MetaData.reflect() method.

print('type(md01): %s' % type(md01))
# type(md01): <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.MetaData'>

md01tbls = md01.tables
print('md01tbls: %s' % md01tbls)
# md01tbls: immutabledict({})
```

So I modified the code accordingly in order to get rid of the warning

```
md02 = MetaData(bind=engine, schema=['SYS', 'SYSTEM']).reflect()
print('type(md02): %s' % type(md02))
# type(md02): <class 'NoneType'>

md02tbls = md02.tables
# Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
#    ...
# File "sqlalchemy_oracle.py", line 44, in <module>
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'

print('md02tbls: %s' % md02tbls)
```

No warning, but an exception instead. :(

After some researching The Net it appeared as if some further code modification is required.

```
md03 = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine, schema=['SYS', 'SYSTEM'])
# Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
#    ...
# File "/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 637, in denormalize_name
#    name_lower = name.lower()
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

print('type(md03): %s' % type(md03))
md03tbls = md03.tables
print('md03tbls: %s' % md03tbls)
```

Even less successful than the previous attempt. Converting the schema names listed to lower case letters lead to the identical result.

So maybe `reflect` can only handle `strings` and no`lists`?

```
md05a = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine, schema='sys')
print('type(md05a): %s' % type(md05a))
# type(md05a): <class 'NoneType'>

md05b = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine, schema='system')
print('type(md05b): %s' % type(md05b))
# type(md05b): <class 'NoneType'>

md05atbls = md05a.tables
# Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
#    ...
# File "sqlalchemy_oracle.py", line 44, in <module>
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'

print('md05atbls: %s' % md05atbls)
md05btbls = md05b.tables
print('md05btbls: %s' % md05btbls)
```

No luck there either!

Maybe it is not possible to reflect the system tables? So lets try user-specific objects.

```
md06 = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine, schema='MYUSR')
print('type(md06): %s' % type(md06))
# type(md06): <class 'NoneType'>

md06tbls = md06.tables
# Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
#    ...
# File "sqlalchemy_oracle.py", line 44, in <module>
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'

print('md06tbls: %s' % md06tbls)
```

Again the already know exception.

Moving back to the deprecated call version.

```
md07 = MetaData(bind=engine, schema=['MYUSR', 'MYUSR2'], reflect=True)
print('type(md07): %s' % type(md07))
# type(md07): <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.MetaData'>

md07tbls = md07.tables
print('md07tbls: %s' % md07tbls)
# md07tbls: immutabledict({})
```

No exception, but no tables either, despite that there are several to be found in the schemas `MYUSR` and `MYUSR2`.

Splitting the `list` into `strings` when specifying the schema.

```
md08a = MetaData(bind=engine, schema='MYUSR', reflect=True)
# Warning: sqlalchemy_oracle.py:37: SADeprecationWarning: The MetaData.reflect flag is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.   Please use the MetaData.reflect() method.

print('type(md08a): %s' % type(md08a))
# ype(md08a): <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.MetaData'>

md08b = MetaData(bind=engine, schema='MYUSR2', reflect=True)
# Warning: sqlalchemy_oracle.py:40: SADeprecationWarning: The MetaData.reflect flag is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.   Please use the MetaData.reflect() method.

print('type(md08b): %s' % type(md08b))
# type(md08b): <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.MetaData'>

md08atbls = md08a.tables
print('md08atbls: %s' % md08atbls)
# md08atbls: immutabledict({'MYUSR.table01': Table(...)})

md08btbls = md08b.tables
print('md08btbls: %s' % md08btbls)
# md08btbls: immutabledict({'MYUSR2.table01': Table(...)})
```

So this attempt finally produced the expected result. :)

From all this it appears as if

1. system/public tables (database objects) cannot be reflected;
2. only user-specific tables can be reflected;
3. only the deprecated version of reflection is working;
4. this behaviour can be observed both with Oracle as well as PostgreSQL databases.

Is there something I overlooked? Something I have mis-perceived? Done wrong, differently from how it actually is intended?

My environment comprises of

- Ubuntu linux 16.04LTS;
- Python 3.8;
- SQLAlchemy 1.3.16;
- cx_Oracle 7.3.0;
- psycopg2 2.8.5;
- local Oracle 18c Instant client;
- remote Oracle 19c database;
- local PostgreSQL 9.5 database.

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres, you can reflect tables in a database's [pg_catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG) schema like this:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///postgres', echo=False)
>>> meta = sa.MetaData()
>>> meta.reflect(engine, schema='pg_catalog')
>>> meta.tables.keys()
(long sequence of table names...)
```

Setting `echo=True` in `create_engine` will output all the queries executed by SQLAlchemy on the system tables when building the metadata, which may help in reverse-engineering the same result for other databases..

Answer (score 2):

Supplementary to @snakecharmerb's answer, this works for me with SQLAlchemy 1.4:

```py
connection_uri = (
    "oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199:1521/"
    "?service_name=xepdb1&encoding=UTF-8&nencoding=UTF-8"
)

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri)

insp = sa.inspect(engine)
print(insp.default_schema_name)
# scott
tables = insp.get_table_names()
print(tables)
# ['table1']
tables = insp.get_table_names(schema="sys")
print(tables)
# ['sqllog$', 'sqlobj$', 'sqlobj$data', 'svcobj$', …
```